# THREE.BufferGeometry showing doubled output, different when browser page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, three.js

`THREE.WebGLRenderer 105`

I'm trying to use THREE.BufferGeometry with a custom shader that switches between 15 textures in order to render pieces of images with characters while each consists of 4 verticies per character. With the basic shader everything looks solid. Textures are prepared using msdf-bmfont.

Uniform fragment (as I see it in the browser console):

```
color: {type: "c", value: Color}
opacity: {type: "f", value: 1}
texture0: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture1: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture2: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture3: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture4: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture5: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture6: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture7: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture8: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture9: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture10: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture11: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture12: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture13: {type: "t", value: Texture}
texture14: {type: "t", value: Texture}
```

Shader fragment:

```
        attribute vec2 uv;
        attribute float page;
        attribute vec4 position;
        uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
        uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying float vPage;
        void main() {
          vUv = uv;
          vPage = page;
          gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * position;
        }
```

Fragment shader looks like this **with conversion to int, suggested by @pailhead**:

```
      precision highp float;
      precision highp int;
      uniform float opacity;
      uniform vec3 color;
      uniform sampler2D texture0; 
uniform sampler2D texture1; 
uniform sampler2D texture2; 
uniform sampler2D texture3; 
uniform sampler2D texture4; 
uniform sampler2D texture5; 
uniform sampler2D texture6; 
uniform sampler2D texture7; 
uniform sampler2D texture8; 
uniform sampler2D texture9; 
uniform sampler2D texture10; 
uniform sampler2D texture11; 
uniform sampler2D texture12; 
uniform sampler2D texture13; 
uniform sampler2D texture14; 

      varying float vPage; // varying cannot be int
      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main() {
        vec4 sampleColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        int iPage = int(vPage);

        if ( iPage == 0) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture0, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 1) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture1, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 2) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture2, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 3) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture3, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 4) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture4, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 5) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture5, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 6) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture6, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 7) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture7, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 8) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture8, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 9) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture9, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 10) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture10, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 11) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture11, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 12) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture12, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 13) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture13, vUv);
        }

        else if ( iPage == 14) {
          sampleColor = texture2D(texture14, vUv);
        }
       else {
          sampleColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
        gl_FragColor = sampleColor * vec4(color, opacity);
         if (gl_FragColor.a < 0.0001) discard;
      }
```

First of all I'm surprised that I had to `floor()` vPage values (WebGL shader language doesn't have `round()`) otherwise I notice that the images simply flicker, constantly jumping between 2 textures for every character. Now I'm even doing conversion to *int*. After these modifications of the shader, reloading the page produces every time some scrambled result on every placeholder for character which means vPage is either not correctly passed which I doubt since every time it's the same (I check in the browser console).

Is it due to something that is left behind between browser page refreshes? If so what could be done to avoid that strange behavior?

[What is seen in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is4Mx.gif)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try casting your floor into an int?

Comment: @pailhead Thank you, edited the snippets. The results are still weird

Comment: If you define a varying variable in a vertex shader, its value will be interpolated over the primitive being rendered. Are you actually aware of this? It should explain why you had to use `floor()` in the fragment shader.